# Creating a Firefox extension that modifies a page that exists on a local web server

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create a Firefox extension that will allow me to modify a page on my company's local web server. I don't have access to modify the source code of the page itself. So in the same spirit of extensions like the [Reddit Enhancement Suite](http://redditenhancementsuite.com/) I'd like to write some code that will inject a CSS file and some javascript to enhance the page on page load for myself and my co-workers.

I've successfully made a Firefox extension that loads in files on regular sites like say google.com and such. But once I change the domain to match the page on my company's local web server (for example: `10.0.0.12:82`), it stops working. Specifically I am attempting to inject a .css file into the page. I am using `resource://` to do it and it works flawlessly on other sites. The CSS is not being injected at all. So it's not a matter of permissions or anything. It seems like the javascript isn't firing.

Is it not possible to do this on a local web server? Perhaps there are extra measures I need to take first since it's not a normal website?

Here is the relevant code from the files in my extension. I set up a path in my manifest file and then in the javascript file that loads I append a css file located at `\chrome\skin\resources` into the `<head>` tag of the loaded page.

**chrome.manifest** file

`resource  cemod    chrome/skin/resources/`

**console.js** file

`$("head").append('<link media="all" href="resource://cemod/page.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>')`

Just to reiterate, this code works fine when the extension is written to activate on other pages like reddit.com. But it stops working once I change it to the IP address of my company's local web server.

Comment: Are you using XHR to get the local files? If you are then the status will be 0 but that's a lie, it really completed succesfully I had thought I had this same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585359/how-to-xhr-local-files/25585841#25585841

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I'm not using XHR to get the css file. I've updated my question with the relevant code I am using and some further explanation.

Comment: You are having the same issue as this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504587/firefox-extension-load-script-from-chrome-url-into-page/30504791?noredirect=1#comment49085734_30504791

Comment: Adding `contentaccessible=true` didn't help me at all. But I did try using the gist you linked and that works for me. So I'm trashing my files and switching to yours instead. Thank you.

Comment: Scratch that. I tried using your gist and it doesn't work fully for me. I load up bing.com and only the injected javascript and .png load. Neither the css nor the iframed html file load.