# firefox extension: load script from chrome:// url into page

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

In my Firefox extension I want to add a JS file to the page.

I tried to do that by adding to the page a script tag with the url to my script:

```
<script src="chrome://path/to/my/script/file.js" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>
```

But nothing happens when I add it to the page.

The script is not visible in the devtools (debugger > sources).

When I enter the same url in the address bar - I do see the file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting a security error, see in browser console it will say chrome url not allowed to be injected. What you have to do is set `contentaccessible=true` on the path which you have files which you want to inject - in your `chrome.manifest` like this: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437#file-chrome-manifest-L1

Comment: I tried using your gist and it doesn't work fully for me. I load up bing.com and only the injected javascript and .png load. Neither the css nor the iframed html file load.