# Get a javascript File object from Firefox sdk file system

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to send a file to a server in the form of a javascript File object. if I send the binary data, it just shows up as corrupted. I had it working last week, but it seems the latest firefox update seems to be preventing the script to run.

Code that worked last week:

```
function readLocalFiles(file) {
    return new Promise(function (done, error) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", 'file:///' + file.path);
        xhr.responseType = "blob";
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                var fileObj = xhr.response;
                fileObj.name = file.name;
                done(fileObj);
            }
        }
        xhr.onerror = function () {
            alert('fudge');
        }
        xhr.send();
    });
}
```

I had added "file:///" in to the permissions of the package.json file just incase.
I have also tried the example here:
 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Using_the_DOM_File_API_in_chrome_code

I can get the files binary data using require("sdk/io/file"), but don't know how i could convert that to a File object, i've seen a few post online about converting binary to an array buffer and passing that as a blob, like: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String?hl=en, but the files just turn out corrupted.

This plugin is for internal use only, so I'm not worried about any security issues that might arise from accessing the users local files. The script basically loops through a designated directory and grabs images and uploads them to the server.

**Edit:**

I just found out that the file:/// call works when using jpm run, but not when the addon is compiled. ignore my comment below, still trying to figure this one out.

Comment: Not sure if I should put this as an answer or not. But I fixed my issue. The string that was being passed in to the ajax call from the object was using backslashes for the dir structure. I replaced them with forward slashes and it solved the issue. I'm just confused as to why it worked last week, and just decided to stop now. It wouldn't even try to make the ajax call, so i figured it was firefox security issue stopping the call with the new update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found, although not the best for security reasons.

my original setup worked because of running it in jpm run, but when compiling it is when it would fail. I guess in jpm run mode it allows for local file access, so to mimic that after compiling I set the firefox setting **security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy** to false.

Just need to remember to set it back when done. I can also try and update the code to use the [preferences/service](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/preferences_service) api to set this on and off for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you XHR a file uri, the readyState always returns 0, however it really does load, as seen here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25585661/1828637

Comment: readyState will return return a different value, status will not